# Isn't it shirk to seek refuge in the perfect words of Allah?

Tags: quran, tawheed, divine-attributes

A‘oothu bi kalimaatil-laahit-taammaati min sharri maa khalaq.
“I seek protection in the perfect words of Allah from every evil that He has created.”

Isn't seeking refuge in the perfect words of Allah shirk? What is the ruling when it comes to seeking refuge?

Comment: the speech of Allah is one of Allah's attributes and therefore permissible to swear by https://islamqa.info/en/122729

Answer (score 7):

No. Why would it be Shirk? - The perfect words of Allah (ﷻ) are **not a creation**; they are His uncreated word and they are of Him. Therefore, seeking refuge in His Word is fine.

Khaula bint Hakim Sulamiyya reported:

> I heard Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) as saying: When anyone lands at a place, and then says:" I seek refuge in the Perfect Word of Allah from the evil of what He has created," nothing would harm him until he marches from that stopping place. [(Sahih Muslim 2708)](https://sunnah.com/muslim/48/72)

Prophet Muhammad (ﷺ) is the one who taught this to us; would he teach other than Tawheed? SubhanAllah. No; nor is there any person who understood Tawheed better than he did. So there should be no doubt.

*Future reference: You may refer to scholarly Books on Tawheed. They do cover this hadith.

Comment: I asking how we can understand this Dua ? Because we know Allah is the one who deserve to be worshipped Isn't this Dua to Allah like "oh Allah(silent), I seek refuge in the perfect words of Allah".We asking to give refuge in his perfect word because he made perfect words a shelter for believers.here not praying to his perfect words .This prayer to Allah.we don't pray to Quran

Comment: The dua is simply in a 3rd person tone. Same reason it says "from every evil that He has created". 'He' rather than 'You.' (Allah). Doesn't mean who we're making dua to is different than the one we're addressing [Allah].

Answer (score 1):

You are asking Allah for xyz by virtue of his names. You are not addressing his names. You are addressing Allah

Further explanation here : https://islamqa.info/en/answers/185053/ruling-on-a-person-saying-o-wisdom-of-allah-or-o-mercy-of-allah